# the new firebase project doesn't appear on the shell

Tags: firebase, firebase-cli

I have been created a new project on the firebase website
I copied this code in my html

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.9/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "ksjdfhkshfjksdhfjksdhfjksdhf",
    authDomain: "myprojectapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://myproject-1734d.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "myproject-1734d",
    storageBucket: "myproject-1734d.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "724771200762"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>
```

I wrote the command line

> firebase init

and there on the shell was shown all my projects except the new one to select. Does anybody know what happened?

Comment: Keep trying.  If it doesn't show up after a while, contact Firebase support.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/

Comment: same here. I've created a new project on the web but It doesn't appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen this problem also. and I found that the project appeared with another command in my case.

try

```
firebase list
```

and If you too

just skip it while initializing with [don't setup a default project] 
after that use the project with

```
firebase use <your-project-id>
```

Answer (score 0):

From firebase console go to the setting (near project overview) and look up the project ID. Then use the following command:

```
firebase init --project <project-ID>
```